# php json_encode options to force non-sequential

Tags: php, json

Is there an option to force the

```
json_encode(array("a", 2, 5));
```

to produce

```
{"0":"a", "1":2, "2":5};
```

I think doing

```
$a =  array("dummy","a", 2, 5);
unset($a[0]);
echo json_encode($a);
```

works, but is there a cleaner way

**edit**:

Sry I actually need

```
$a =  array (array("a"), array(2,3), array(5,6,7));
echo json_encode($a, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

to give:

```
{"0":["a"],"1":[2 , 3],"2":[5, 6, 7]}
```

instead of

```
{"0":{"0":"a"},"1":{"0":2,"1":3},"2":{"0":5,"1":6,"2":7}}
```

any idea?

seems

```
$a =  array ("", array("a"), array(2,3), array(5,6,7));
unset($a[0]);
echo json_encode($a);
```

is the only way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
json_encode( (object) array(

  array( "a" ), array( 2, 3 ), array( 5, 6, 7 )

) );
```

Comment: The "array" implementation in PHP is nicer than in a lot of languages, including JavaScript, and Ruby prior to 1.9. The "array" type in PHP is a combination of numerically indexed arrays and associative key-value map / hash / dict functionality. Keys consisting of digits are converted to integers. `json_encode()` assumes you want arrays with sequential, zero-based integer keys to be converted to JS arrays. Other PHP arrays are converted to JS objects (which munge object and map functionality). You can request to have a sequentially numerically indexed array converted to a JS object.

Comment: @Ignacio Also, in case this is what you're driving at, JS doesn't have integer "keys" for objects -- it converts them to strings.

Comment: perfect, my need is actually is little more complicated, sry for the edit

Comment: Ok, revised my answer. By the way, my comments were in reply to a comment by an "Ignacio". I forget to @ reply him in the first one, then he deleted the comment. Just wanted to let you know it wasn't directed at you.